# There are n husbands and n wives to be seated at... Find var(X)

Tags: probability, expectation, uniform-distribution, variance

There are n husbands and n wives to be seated at a long rectangular
table. All of the husbands will sit on one side of the
table and all of the wives will sit on the other side. Let X be
the number of husbands that sit across from their wives. Find
var(X).

---

I've setted $X_i=1$ If husband seats across his wife and $X_i=0$ otherwise 
(with $i=1,2....n$).

Also, $P(X_i=1)$=$1\over n$,

I then have: $E(X_i)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_iP_X(x_i=1)=1$.

From the variance definition, I can have: $Var(X_i)=E(X_i^2)-(E(X_i))^2$

After that, I'm a bit stuck. 
Can I just continue with my last line

> $Var(X_i)=E(X_i^2)-(E(X_i))^2$

and then apply a $\sum_i^n$ on the expectations?

Or can I just write more on the line of:

> $Var(X_i)= \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ with $i\in [0,n]$

Any help or tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't just add up the variances, because the $X_i$'s are not independent. The formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables) might be useful, but there may be a simpler way to think about your problem.

Comment: Also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666066/probability-of-couples-seating-arrangements-at-a-rectangular-table?rq=1) might be of help.

Comment: "The sum of correlated variables formula" would be the key but I can't find the intuition behind it in order to apply it. Since It hasn't been announced in the book I'm following.

Comment: This is also known as 'hat check problem', 'problem of derangements', among others. $E(X) = V(X) = 1,$ for all $n > 1.$ Seem to recall $V(X) = 1$ can be shown by induction with indicator variables. Distribution POIS(1) fits well for $n \ge 10,$ but note that $P(X > n) = P(X = n-1) = 0.$

Comment: One proof that $V(X) = 1$ is in the first few pages of these [_class notes_](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/70477/6-042j-fall-2002/contents/lecture-notes/cp13Wsol.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment.** Because you can google several proofs online, including the one
in my earlier comment for the 'hat check' incarnation, maybe it is worthwhile
to illustrate the reasonably good fit to $\mathsf{Pois}(1)$ using simulation
in R. With a million iterations one can expect at least two place accuracy.

```
set.seed(412);  m = 10^6;  n = 12
x = replicate(m, sum(sample(n)==1:n))
mean(x);  sd(x);  table(x)/m
[1] 1.001044       # aprx E(X) = 1
[1] 0.999903       # aprx SD(X) = 1
x
       0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
0.367157 0.368324 0.184228 0.061268 0.015332 0.003110 0.000495 0.000076 0.000010 

hist(x, prob=T, br=(-1:n)+.5, col="skyblue2")
k = 0:n; pdf = dpois(k, 1);  points(k, pdf, col="red")
```

The histogram below shows the simulated distribution of $X$ and the
centers of red circles show probabilities of $\mathsf{Pois}(1).$

[image]

*Note:*  By one of @TheoreticalEconomist's links, $P(X = 0) = \sum_{i=0}^{12} (-1)^i/i! = 0.3679.$

```
i=0:12;  sum((-1)^i/factorial(i))
[1] 0.3678794
```

Comment: This is cool -- do you have any intuition for why the Poisson distribution is a good fit? It would be nice if an explanation were in your answer (even a brief one).

Comment: (1) Getting your own hat back (or sitting opposite your own spouse) will be more and more rare as $n$ increases. Also, as $n$ increases other matches have less effect on one's own match. So it does not seem unreasonable to view matches as random events modeled by POIS(1). // (2) Once you know $E(X) = V(X)$ for a discrete distribution, the Poisson springs to mind, because it is a 'familiar' distribution with this property. Because $E(X) = 1$ then the reasonable guess is POIS(1) // The number of matches in the famous birthday problem is also approx. Poisson, but the fit isn't quite so good.

Comment: (3) The formula in my note [your ref] for $P(X=0)$ is the beginning of the Maclauren expansion of $e^{-1} = e^{-\lambda},$ which is $P(X=0)$ for $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 1).$ // The surprise is not that POIS(1) is some kind of an approximation; the surprise is that the approx is so good.